# Function within a controller is not working

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

I have a controller with Index function, Now i am trying to make a more fundtion for on scroll pagintion in codeignitor Controller.
This is my function

```
public function load_more($cat2,$cat1)
        { 
       $group_no = $this->input->post('group_no');
        $content_per_page = 12;
        $start = ceil($group_no * $content_per_page);
        $all_content = $this->product__model->get_all_content($start,$content_per_page,$cat2,$cat1);
        if(isset($all_content) && is_array($all_content) && count($all_content)) : 
            foreach ($all_content as $key => $content) :
                 echo '<li>'.$content->id.'</li>';
                 echo '<p>'.$content->ITEM_CODE.'</p>';                 
            endforeach;                                
        endif; 
        }
```

Controller name is Product 
When i check this fucntion at my url its hows page not found...
this is URL

http://www.dezaro.com/Product/load_more/160/2

How can i resolve it ???

Comment: Might be routes problem

Comment: $route['product/load_more'] = "product/load_more/$1";    "I added this code to route but still not working"

Comment: Its working try this  http://www.dezaro.com/product/load_more/160/2 (lowercase product ). Its because you define routes in lowercase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Siddharth vyas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6573930/siddharth-vyas) The issue is with your URL you are hitting. Use product instead Product.

So Use http://www.dezaro.com/product/load_more/160/2 instead of

http://www.dezaro.com/Product/load_more/160/2

It will work for sure. Because it take the filename instead of Classname.

Comment: its working.. but its calling some another function from model

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$route['method/(:any)/(:any)'] = 'controller/method/$1/$2';
```

your route should be

```
$route['method/(:cat1)/(:cat2)'] = 'product/load_more/$1/$2';
```

Answer (score 0):

It seemd you are facing issue of index.php
Please try using url:

```
http://www.dezaro.com/index.php/Product/load_more/160/2
```

Comment: i hide it by htaccess

Comment: can you please share your controller code. bcz its working if I remove load_more.